# Windows Phone 7 animation

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm using turnstyle animation. It animates smoothly when entering with the Load event but when I use the BackKeyPressed event it navigates too fast on the previous page without finishing the animation. How do I make the transition slower when I'm using turnstyle control?

Comment: I assume you're using the toolkit for your turnstyle animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing this behaviour in the emulator or on an actual device?

If in the emulator I wouldn't worry about it. This is not typical of the actual devices.

The timing of the animations in the toolkit are designed to match those used by the OS and so, on a real device, you should see them looking fine. However, if you really want to change the behaviours you could get the source for the toolkit and edit the storyboards to meet your need.

Comment: Emulator. Well, I dont need to edit the storyboards because I have no problem with that. If I added two button controls that handles my enter and exit animation it runs smoothly. But when I press the back key it cuts the storyboard and loads the main page.

Answer (score 1):

I too have the same problem. Apparently, it seems that "heavy" pages don't run the animation smoothly. I have a page with a bing map embedded onto it. Entering this page never shows animation, exiting it shows a turnstile transition.